# Segmentation fault (core dumped) read from stdin

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to count the number of each word in a file. The file can be either stdin or a filename provided on the command line(./count -f ). So far the program gives the correct outputs when reading a file from command line. But an error happens when i am trying to read from stdin. The program first output the correct, then give a Segmentation fault (core dumped). Here is part of my code.

```
    FILE * fp;
int size = 20000;
char sentence[2000]; // the sentence from stdin
if ( argc != 3 ) 
{
    fgets(sentence,sizeof(sentence),stdin); // read from stdin
    fflush(stdin);
    // I think the initialization of word is incorrect, but i do know why it is incorrect
    char *word = strtok (sentence," !\"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\n\t");
    while (word != NULL)
    {
        get_word(word); // get each word
        word = strtok (NULL, " !\"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\n\t");
    }
}
else
{
    fp = fopen( argv[2], "r" );
    if ( fp == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Could not open file\n" );
    }

           char word[1000];
    while (readFile(fp, word, size)) {  // let the program read the file
        get_word(word); // get each word. Works well.
    }
}
```

get_word function:

```
void get_word(char *word){
node *ptr = NULL;
node *last = NULL;

if(first == NULL){
    first = add_to_list(word); // add to linked list
    return;
}

ptr = first;
while(ptr != NULL){
    if(strcmp(word, ptr->str) == 0){
        ++ptr->freq;
        return;
    }
    last = ptr;            
    ptr = ptr->next;  
}
last->next = add_to_list(word); // add to linked list
```

}

Please help me figure out why i get a segmentation fault(core dumped).
The program works on my mac, but does not work on Linux.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` triggers undefined behavior. What does `get_word` do ?

Comment: It's not the root cause, but you should not be calling `fflush(stdin);` -- fflush is undefined for input streams.

Comment: No it is not the fflush(stdin) problem.I deleted it, but still get the error. I think it is a memory problem. THe program works on my mac, but does not work on Linux.

Comment: At what line does it crash?

Comment: @Joe It does not crash until it outputs the correct result.

Comment: What does `get_word` do?

Comment: get each word, it works perfectly. Since when i read input files, the program gives the correct output.

Comment: @user605947 Please post the code of `get_word`. It's the prime candidate for the cause of the segfault.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE * fp;

    if ( argc != 3 )
    {
            fgets(sentence,sizeof(sentence),stdin);
            // and so on
    }
    else
    {
            fp = fopen( argv[2], "r" );
            if ( fp == 0 )
            {
                    printf( "Could not open file\n" );
            }
            while (readFile(fp, word, size)) {
                    get_word(word);
            }
    }

    // do some stuff, sorting etc.

    fclose(fp);
```

that you `fclose(fp)` regardless of whether it was opened. If `fp` is not connected to a valid stream, a segmentation fault is common. Apparently some implementations handle a `NULL` argument to `fclose` gracefully, and that's what makes it appear to work on Mac.

Move the `fclose` call into the `else` branch, and when `fopen` fails, don't just

```
printf( "Could not open file\n" );
```

but end the programme.

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel. Big Help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Help (and interesting puzzles) is why I'm here.

Answer (score 0):

sentences size is 2 kib, and you're reading 2 kib from stdin. after that you use a string function on it. strings are ending with an '\0', but since you read 2 kib data without '\0', there is no string-end, so it segfaults, because the string function (strtok in this case) is probably working far beyond 2 kin.

Comment: I tested it with only one character.